# Inverted search full text/similar with dirty search term

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a small problem regarding the search of a string against a database.

Imagine this situation.
I have a table with all cars make and models, something similar to this:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------+
|           name            | alternative_names |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| Peugeot 207               |                   |
| Peugeot 208               |                   |
| Peugeot 308               |                   |
| Peugeot 308 Station Wagon | estate sw         |
| Peugeot 307               |                   |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to identify the car saved on the db starting from a string that most of the times is dirty.

*"peugeot 308"* should return **Peugeot 308**

*"peugeot 308 station wagon"* should return **Peugeot 308 Station Wagon**

*"automatic peugeot 308"* should return **Peugeot 308**

*"sw peugeot 308"* should return **Peugeot 308 Station Wagon**

Any idea how I should approach and solve this problem?

Comment: Well. Explain more about alternative_names field. What does that contains?

Comment: I see this situation (automatic peugeot 308" should return Peugeot 308)

Comment: It seems that you are trying to return values if it at least contains one of the words provided in the search query

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to foresee all posiible dirty words, so better to create helper in PHP what will make words with uppercase first letter and replace words like `sw` to `Station Wagon`

```
function modelNormalizer($model)
{

    $possible_replace = [
        'sw' => 'Station Wagon',
    ];

    $byWord = explode(' ', $model);

    foreach ($byWord as $i => $word) {
        foreach ($possible_replace as $from => $to) {
            $byWord[$i] = ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace($from, $to, $word)));
        }
    }

    return implode(' ', $byWord);
}
```

Also you can normalize data in DB, for example with moving words before `peugeot` to the end.

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(SUBSTR(t.name, LOCATE('peugeot 308', t.name)), ' ', SUBSTR(t.name, 1, LOCATE('peugeot 308', t.name)-1)) AS model
FROM yourtable AS t
WHERE t.name like "%peugeot 308%" #WARNING YOUR INDEX WILL NOT WORK WITH % PREFIX
```